# specify a different name for table|column name in EF4

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm using EF4 with CodeFirst

```
public class People : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Human> Humans { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

At the moment, EF looks in the database for the `Human` table. How can I specify for it to look for `Humans` instead?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can change table name on `Human` class:

```
[Table("Humans")]
public class Human
{
    ...
}
```

Other way is to use Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Human>()
    .ToTable("Humans");
```

Similary you can use `ColumnAttribute` or `HasColumnName` method to change the name of column.

Comment: Very useful!  I had been fixing these up manually at each migration creation.

Comment: I just want to note, that Model building is only performed for first instance of given DbContext-derived class. Then it's cached for future instances. So 'MyDbContext.OnModelCreating()' (where Fluent context configuration usually happens) is only called once in your app. -- This prevents having really dynamic Table name for each instance of DbContext. -- I'm writing this because I found out the hard way. Might save some headache for somebody :)